# const check = (user) => `Good ${user}` をアロー関数を使わずに書くとどうなる？

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
   const check = (user) => `Good ${user}`
```

**アロー関数を使わない場合**、どう書けば良いでしょうか？

---

```
const check = function(user) {
 return ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
>            // equivalent to:  => { return expression; }

アロー関数では1行の式の場合、`return`を省略できることになっています。
省略せずに書くと下記のようになります。

```
const check = (user) => { return `Good ${user}`; }
```

そのため、functionを使用して書くと下記のようになります。

```
const check = function(user) {
  return `Good ${user}`;
};
```

Template literalsの`` `Good ${user}` ``と`"Good " + user`は等価ですので、お好きな方を使用してください。

```
const check = function(user) {
  return "Good " + user;
};
```

Template literals
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation

Google Chrome等であれば下記のスニペットで確認ができるかと思います。

---

```js
const check = (user) => `Good ${user}`;

const _check = function(user) { return "Good " + user; };

console.log(check("user"));

console.log(_check("user"));
```